# an issue with Firebase Realtime Database ( android client )

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i had a weird issue with Firebase Realtime Database , i have 2 android apps sharing the same database , database structure :

```
user{

id{
kind:value1,
name:value2,
commission:value3
...
...
}
}
```

in the first app , value1 is  "taxi" , in the second app "client" , i'm setting those values only once when user sign up , i'm doing it this way :

```
databaseReference.child("user").child(id).setValue(new User());
```

User class :

```
class User{

String kind = "taxi",commission="0" ... ;

}
```

in the other app :

```
  class User{

    String kind = "client", ... ;

  }
```

the issue is with one user from the "taxi" app , when he signed up the "kind" field was set to "client" instead of "taxi" , also "commission" field was missing in the database , i can't understand how this can happen ?

Comment: Are they sharing the ID? You may be overwritting your record

Comment: @RodrigoMata no , i'm using auto-generated ids ( firebase user uid ) , also other fields are fine the problem is just with "kind" and "commission"

Comment: The device/emulator that you used, do they have same UID? this can happen when you are using the same device for both client and taxi

Comment: @MRah firebase uid can be duplicated for 2 accounts ?

Comment: No, but if it's the same device then the account is the same. If a client for example also downloaded the taxi app. The device is the same, so UID should be the same (afaik), a simple solution is adding taxi/client with the UID when saving it in database, so even same device has both apps they have 2 different ids

Comment: @MRah i'm not using device id , i'm using the firebase account id , it should never be the same even if it is the same device .